# xcode 4.0.2 Hang in checking source control status

Tags: xcode, freeze

I am having problem with the xcode. When i start the xcode for a while, it automatically shows"checking source control status" and just hang there and the colorful wheel of loading appear. May I Know how can i solve the problem?

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you using SVN? Did you update to Mac Os X 10.6.8?

Comment: Bringing this one back from the dead, I'm on Xcode 6.1 OSX 10.10 and running into this for the first time. It's not quite hanging so much as deadly slow.